# Spring repository caching

Tags: spring, hibernate, caching, spring-data-jpa, repository

I am writing an application with Spring 5 and Hibernate. There's a service that receives an entity in a different state than currently persisted. It performs some processing and saves the entity to database (using Spring CrudRepository).

```
public void saveEntity(Entity entity) {
    ProcessingStatus processingStatus = doSomeProcessing(entity);
    if (processingStatus == ProcessingStatus.SUCCESS) {
        entity.setProcessingStatus(ProcessingStatus.SUCCESS);
        repository.save(entity);
    } else {
        Entity originalEntity = repository.findById(entity.getId());
        originalEntity.setProcessingStatus(ProcessingStatus.FAILURE);
        repository.save(originalEntity);
    }
}
```

So if processing was successful we're just marking entity with success status and save it. Otherwise any changes that comes with new version of entity shouldn't be applied. So original entity from repository is retrieved, its status is changed and then it is saved.

The problem is that line

```
Entity originalEntity = repository.findById(entity.getId());
```

actually retrieves already modified object (probably cached by Hibernate?), not the original one from database. So *originalEntity* has the same set of attributes as *entity* (received as method argument). What would be the best way to retrieve original object in such case?

Comment: before starting processing (doSomeProcessing()), fetch the original object first then process for processing (doSomeProcessing()).

Comment: It would have the same effect. That's because input entity is an object fetched from db and altered somehow. So even if I fetch original object in the first line of this method it would already be not the original one.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this `saveEntity` method is annotated with `@Transactional`.

For this reason, also if not explicitly stored to with `repository.save(entity)`, you have your update object because you are in the same hibernate session.

You can `detach` your modified entity and then you will read the clean one (**WARNING!** if your entity has not been already persisted you will get a **null**)

To detach and Entity you have to inject `PersistenceContext` in your repository

```
@Repository
public class EntityRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void detachOrderItem(Object object) {
        entityManager.detach(object);
    }
}
```

And then you have to call detach **before** `findById`

```
} else {

    entityRepository.detach(entity);

    Entity originalEntity = repository.findById(entity.getId());
    originalEntity.setProcessingStatus(ProcessingStatus.FAILURE);
    repository.save(originalEntity);
}
```

Another simpler solution could be to run `public void saveEntity(Entity entity)` out of a Transaction (only nested method could live a a transaction)